# Connecting to a multiple databases in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I have an oracle database "DB_V1" that I connect to using the Java code snippet below.

```
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//PATH_HERE:1122/KEN1";
String user = "SMITH[DB_V1]";
String password = "myPassWord";

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS");
resultSet.next();
System.out.println(resultSet.getString("PRODUCT_CODE"));
```

In the image below, you can see my DB_V1 database but I also have access to view the database "FM". How can I access the tables in that database using JDBC? I tried changing user to "SMITH[FM]" but it gives me a wrong credentials error.

[image]

I also tried user "SMITH" and the code below. But that also gave me a bad credentials message.

```
stmt.execute ( "SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=FM");
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't exactly related but you really should try to use `PreparedStatement` over `Statement`, `Statement` is a security flaw and is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: @Nexevis With the queries as shown, there is no problem with using `Statement`. Using `PreparedStatement` is only really relevant if you have parameterized queries.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It looks like he is doing this for learning purposes to me and it is good practice to learn PreparedStatement in my opinion, as it is what you will use in a real world scenario. Also if you use PreparedStatement from the start it will make your code easier to modify if you decide to take user input later (or someone else on the project) and you will nit have the possibility of losing security by accident. I do not see an advantage of ever using Statement, unless you some good reason? Is it slightly faster?

Comment: @Nexevis I agree that usually using PreparedStatements is better (because you really use unparameterized statements in 'real' applications. But, depending on the specifics of a database and driver implementation, it might be faster because it doesn't need to prepare the statement, and you can use a single statement handle to execute multiple different statements.

Comment: Good stuff, good stuff. I'm glad this is generating discussions on prepared statements vs statements. 

Now, does anyone have any ideas on my actual question.